# Vuex and form handling, how to not update state before submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a form that displays data from a Vuex store, that allows the user to update the form fields, then press submit when ready.

So far I've only seen tutorials using v-model with computed `get()` and `set()` to read in the store values and then directly update them.

But I would like to intuitively let the user change the form and then decide to either update, or cancel. Canceling would reset the form essentially to the original state values.

So far all I have figured out is the v-model method, which is not ideal as it propagates the data everywhere that state value is used. So it can affect logic when it shouldn't until the user has pressed submit

```
<v-text-field v-model="displayName"></v-text-field>

...

computed: {
...mapGetters(['currentUser']),
    displayName: {
        get() {
            return this.currentUser.name
        },
        set(value) {
            this.$store.dispatch('updateName', value);
        },
    },
}
```

I just cannot figure out how to show the current state but also in a Vue kind of way update the state only when a button is pressed. Is there a good tutorial out there for this?

**Dirty idea** have it update a temporary state, and when submit is pressed it will take the temporary state and update the actual state, as well as propagate it to the database?

---

Followed this tutorial https://medium.com/js-dojo/maintaining-a-single-source-of-truth-while-handling-form-data-with-vuex-426e86d16642

Comment: I may have had an epiphany. I could let the user update the state, and then have a separate action to call the api to update the database. So the local state will be changed until they login again, but if they hit submit it will propogate the change to the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest at the bottom of your post, you could keep the form state locally. When the component loads, fetch the data from the store and copy it into local state. When the user hits save, then you can dispatch an action to make the API request and update the store.

You could also take the route mentioned in your comment, but then if the user chooses to abandon their edit you'll need to reload the original values from the server.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing after I found this tutorial https://medium.com/js-dojo/maintaining-a-single-source-of-truth-while-handling-form-data-with-vuex-426e86d16642. It keeps a local copy in the component, then when the form is submitted it sends it to the store to be updated.